# Wikipedia API - get the links to searched results

Tags: java, api, search, hyperlink, wikipedia

Ok, this should be a childlishy easy task but I really can't find an answer for that. I want to make a Java application that would search wikipedia (with a given search query) and return a link to the most relevant article. Simple as that. I don't want to edit the content, parse through, export internal/external links. I just want it to return a link to the searched article. I have been browsing through Wikipedia API and found this action that should be helpful:

http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API%3AQuery

But it doesn't return a link. And I don't know how can I form a link using the Page ID. Maybe I need to ask another thing?

I feel stupid to ask this but really I can't get a straight answer from the tons of possibilities Wiki API offers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Query of the form `http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&title=<query>` returns  titles of the pages (among other things).  `http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/<title>` is your link to the page.

Comment: Thanks! Actually if you change the format to xml it has an entry URL with the address.